# Validate URL's for length, captial letters and certain whole words?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a bit of code which takes the URL that someone chooses when signing up with my app and checks it. But I'd like to add the following restraints to it.

- Must be at least 3 letters
- No capitol letters
- No certain words "admin, support, etc..."

Here's what I have so far - but it's only looking for special letters now:

```
elseif($action == "validate"){

    $option = $_GET["option"];

    $value = $_GET["value"];

    switch($option){

    case "URL":             

$sql = mysql_select_db($value,$connect);
if(preg_match ( "@[^A-Za-z0-9]+@i", $value ) > 0) { $valid = "FALSE";   continue; }

$sql == 1 ?  $valid = "FALSE" : $valid = "TRUE";

}
```

Comment: Why are you using string literals for your `true` and `false`?

Comment: It's part of the form validation if it's a FALSE value the user form picks it up and gives the user a chance to change it. Why ? :)

Comment: @saluce yes, numbers are okay

Comment: The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search, therefore doing both A-Z and a-z in your regex character class is not necessary as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elseif($action == "validate"){

    $option = $_GET["option"];

    $value = $_GET["value"];

    switch($option){

    case "URL":             

    $sql = mysql_select_db($value,$connect);
    if(preg_match ( "@[^A-Za-z0-9]+@i", $value ) > 0) { $valid = "FALSE";   continue; }
    if(strlen($value) <= 3) { $valid = "FALSE";   continue; } //less than 3 char
    if(strstr($value, 'admin')) { $valid = "FALSE";   continue; }
      //.. the same for your other words

    $sql == 1 ?  $valid = "FALSE" : $valid = "TRUE";

}
```

Comment: would it be reliable to condense that down with the || or conditions?

Comment: @JasonHerndon that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match("@^[a-z0-9]{3,25}$@", $value ) && (!preg_match("@admin|support|anything else@",$value))) { 
    //Restrict the word length to 25 characters at max, 3 at least.
    //Do some stuff. The $value meets the requirements as set forth
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - any reason you used && instead of || ? Just wondering?

Comment: @WilliamH, because it must meet all the conditions to be valid

Comment: @WilliamH If you use the `||` (or) operator, then the expected behavior [will not occur](http://ideone.com/RcSI0) (constrain the `$value` to length and characters, **AND** ensure it is not a reserved or denied word)

Comment: Won't quite work, as the first preg_match will match non-alphanumeric characters.  You should make it `preg_match("@[a-z0-9]{3,25}$@", $value)` to match only lowercase a-z and numbers 0-9 (as mentioned in comments on question) from 3 to 25 letters.

Comment: @saluce Fixed my character class.

Comment: You are still negating, so now you are getting the opposite behavior than desired in the first preg_match =)

Comment: I wish I was not so new as to not be able to upvote you guys - thanks for the help. I'll be changing it as you suggested @saluce and PenguinCoder

Comment: @saluce No, I do not see the negation of the character class. The `^` for the word start was moved outside the character class, which is [working as expected](http://ideone.com/kiLPI) and denying the `if` if there is an uppercase english letter.

Comment: Blame it on tired eyes, I didn't see that =)

Comment: @WilliamH Upvotes, answer acceptanced, and (as Saluce has done) correcting my attempts at code, are acceptable thanks!